# Changed Logging Event Level in Appender

Tags: java, mockito, log4j2

Unit under test:

```
package sample;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class App {
   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

   public void doSomething() {
      logger.error("Cannot do something");
   }
}
```

I understand asserting on logger statements on unit under test is not good practice.
Would like to understand why the following code which does just that

```
package sample;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class TestApp {

  @Test
  public void testDoSomething() {
    App app = new App();

    Appender mockedAppender = mock(Appender.class);
    when(mockedAppender.getName()).thenReturn("MockAppender");
    when(mockedAppender.isStarted()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mockedAppender.isStopped()).thenReturn(false);
    ArgumentCaptor<LogEvent>  logEventCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LogEvent.class);
    Logger appLogger = (Logger)LogManager.getLogger(App.class);
    appLogger.addAppender(mockedAppender);
    app.doSomething();

    verify(mockedAppender).append(logEventCaptor.capture());
    LogEvent logEvent = logEventCaptor.getValue();
    assertEquals(logEvent.getLevel(), Level.ERROR);

    appLogger.removeAppender(mockedAppender);
  }
}
```

has logged event changed from ERROR to OFF on the

```
expected: <OFF> but was: <ERROR>
Expected :OFF
Actual   :ERROR
<Click to see difference>

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <OFF> but was: <ERROR>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
```

added appender.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted by Jasvant, the problem with your code is that Log4j 2.x by default uses mutable objects (cf. [`ReusableMessage`](https://s.apache.org/1t5yy) and [`MutableLogEvent`](https://s.apache.org/bxfl8)). These objects are reset after usage, so `logEvent.level` in your code contains the value `null`.

You can solve this problem in two ways:

- either you use [`ListAppender`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/2.x/log4j-core-test/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/test/appender/ListAppender.java) from `log4j-core-test`, which stores **immutable** logging events in a list,
- or you set the `log4j2.enableThreadlocals` to `false`, in which case all events will be immutable (cf. [system properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#system-properties)).

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public Level getLevel() {
    if (level == null) {
        level = Level.OFF; // LOG4J2-462, LOG4J2-465
    }
    return level;
}
```

The above code is found in org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.MutableLogEvent it is to workaround bugs LOG4J2-462 and LOG4J2-465

Comment: The above answer from me points to the code where level is being set from ERROR to OFF. The asker of question has already upvoted this answer. I will appreciate if two unrelated persons who have downvoted this answer remove their downvote.

Comment: The OP didn't upvote your answer. Your answer lacks details, but it points in the right direction. Log4j 2.x usually uses [`ReusableMessage`](https://s.apache.org/1t5yy)s, which are cleared after they have been used (i.e. `Appender#append` was called). Please modify your answer to allow people to modify their votes.